# Connes’ homology

Tags: homological-algebra

Is Connes’ homology $H_*^\lambda(F)$ of algebras $F=\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ or $F=\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(x^p)$ known for $p$ prime where
$\mathbb{Z}_p= \mathbb{Z}/p$ ?